# Office.js Bindings Not Recognized in Opposite Platform (Office Online vs Office Desktop)

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, ms-word, office-js

We are developing javascript office Add-Ins for Excel and Word.  Our users will use Office Desktop and Office Online.

When the user creates a new record in the Add-In, we create a binding on the range that currently has focus. The binding is getting created and appears to be fine, but if the user creates the binding in Office Desktop, and later opens the document in Office Online, then the bindings are not recognized. And vice-versa, if bindings are created in Office Online, they are not later recognized by Desktop.

Is there a better way to do this?

See our code below for our example in Excel:

```
addNote() {
  try {
    Excel.run((ctx) => {
      const selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
      selectedRange.load('address');

      return ctx.sync().then(() => {
        const currentAddress = selectedRange.address;
        this.setState({ currentAddress });

        const bindingName = `SymphonyBinding_${newGuid()}`;
        const myBindings = Office.context.document.bindings;
        this.setState({ bindingName });
        myBindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(currentAddress, 'matrix', { id: bindingName },
          (result) => {
            if (result.status === 'succeeded') {
              this.setState({ bindingName: result.value.id });
              meow.raise({ name: 'create-new-note', context: { tags: [result.value.id] } });
            } else {
              this.setState({ bindingName: 'could not bind' });
            }
          });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    handleError('Office Add-In', error, error.message);
  }
}
```

And here is the code that recognizes the binding:

```
showNoteRequested({ context }) {
  const { note } = context;
  note.tags.forEach((tag) => {
    if (tag.name.indexOf('SymphonyBinding_') !== -1) {
      this.setState({ bindingName: tag.name }, this.selectRange);
    }
  });
}

selectRange() {
  const { bindingName } = this.state;
  try {
    Excel.run((ctx) => {
      const foundBinding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem(bindingName);
      const myRange = foundBinding.getRange();
      myRange.select();
      myRange.load('address');
      return ctx.sync().then(() => {
        const currentAddress = myRange.address;
        this.setState({ currentAddress });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    handleError('Office Add-In', error, error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that attempts to recognize the binding?

Comment: How are you loading your add-in in each environment (sideloaded? Central Deployment?)

Comment: We have tested two ways - sideloaded manifest file and the Apps for Office SharePoint catalog.

Comment: Rick, I updated to original post to include the code that recognizes the bindings.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried word rich client/online? I have fixed a similar issue for word online, so I think you should not see this on word.

Comment: Try using [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment). Settings/bindings are stored in the document by the add-in's ID and sideloaded add-ins get a random ID each assigned when you install it. Centralized Deployment ensures they're all using the same ID:

Comment: Jipyua, we do not have this problem in Word client/online.  Thank you for your attention to this.

Comment: Marc, We don't see the issue with Word.  Do you still think the problem is because we are not using Centralized Deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Is the following binding creation code equivalent to what you have in addNode? It seems to work fine for me when the file is loaded in Excel Online build 16.0.9229.5030.

```
function run() {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        const selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        selectedRange.load('address');

        return ctx.sync().then(() => {
            const currentAddress = selectedRange.address;
            const bindingName = 'SymphonyBinding_{493332C3-F66B-41BF-B37E-8E28D045E2F0}';
            const myBindings = Office.context.document.bindings;
            console.log("binding name" + bindingName);
            myBindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(currentAddress, 'matrix', { id: bindingName },
                (result) => {
                    console.log("binding created");
                });
        });
    });
}
```